# Googlebot not indexing language subdirectory

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, google-index, 302-redirect

I've language based subdirectories, which is changed by user's country.

Let's say if user request from Poland

```
example.com 302 redirects to example.com/pl
example.com/pl 301 redirects to example.com/pl/
```

I have a line with `example.com/pl/` in my `sitemap.xml` file and also on home page my logo has a link which has a direct link to `example.com/pl/`

But there is not any indexed pages when I search on Google with `site:example.com/pl` or `example.com/pl/`

But other pages are indexed like `example.com/pl/references`,  `example.com/pl/clients`.

What should I do?

Comment: How are you able to detect the user's country to redirect them to the /pl/ directory? I've been wanting to setup my site like that for a long time. Are you using a country-IP api? --- It's possible that Google just hasn't indexed your /pl/ pages yet. You could also add href lang and country tags to those pages. This could help Google understand that these pages are useful for people in Poland, and it may index them as a result.

Comment: Have you tried Fetch as Googlebot? You could also use a HTTP Header Checking tool to verify that the page that's not indexed is returning a 200 code (found). If it's returning a 301 or 302 or a redirect loop, Google will think it's not really there. You might also want to check your canonical URL as that might be making Google ignore your page.

Comment: @Michaeld I'm getting user's country with ip adres, https://ipstack.com/product

Comment: @WebElaine, yes I've fetched as google and it seems to be there isn't any problem. and yes I've checked example.com/pl/ is returning 200. I don't actually have canonical url beacuse I don't have a duplicate page.